# facebook like box wont except "like" on WordPress site and FB login box keeps popping up

Tags: facebook, wordpress, authentication, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

Any assistance will and is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I used code generated by Facebook Developer and inserted the code into this WordPress site page:http://www.stilehair.com/studio code is below. When I open the page it looks right, **BUT** when I click on the "Like" button a pop-up appears and asks me to log into FB (even though I am already logged into FB.) 
The box shakes and asks me again and never excepts my correct log in info, Nor does it except the "like".

- This happens on all my browsers, iphone and ipad.
- All software is up to date.
- I've cleared the Cache'.
- Tried numerous attempts at altering the code and/or method of inserting box.
- Ran it through the FB Debugger
- Searched the boards for answers and no solution is working.

  ```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  // ]]></script>


  <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/Stilehair" 
  data-width="292" data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="false" 
  data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
  ```

I've researched several other questions with no results to help rectify my challenge.
Adding a like box seems like such an easy thing to do from all I've read on Facebook and Forums.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you inserting this through the wordpress editor on page?? if yes then place it on page.php/sidebar.php(whr u want) with conditional tags for particular page conditions

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am inserting text on the "Edit Page" for the "Studio" page. I added code to page.php but what do I put for conditional tags? I only want it to show on this one page.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code on my clients wordpress sites.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" show_faces="true" width="450" send="true"></fb:like>
```

the above code is working fine on all of my clients wordpress blogs. For example view any post page [[link]](http://2experts.net)